# Delegate and UIActivityIndicatorView error

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

And just that I'm exercising the delegated pattern. I created a simple application where a delegate sends a message to **UIViewController** saying if you stop or start **UIActivityIndicatorView**. Unfortunately I get the following error: error atal: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.
It would seem that **UIActivityIndicatorView** is not initialized. I can not understand where I'm wrong.

```
    protocol ProgressBarDelegate {
        func UpdateProgressBar(progress: Bool)
    }


    class Dao: NSObject {

        var delegate: ProgressBarDelegate?
        override init() {
            super.init()
           //DELEGATO
            //I who should I send the message? to FirstViewController
            let messaggero = FirstViewController()
            self.delegate = messaggero
            scriviUnMessaggio(progress: true)
        }
 func scriviUnMessaggio(progress: Bool){
        print("I'm writing a message ...")
        delegate?.UpdateProgressBar(progress:progress)      
    }
```

**My controller**

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController,ProgressBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet  var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    func UpdateProgressBar(progress: Bool){

        print("I received the message from Dao class (the delegate)")

        switch progress{
        case true:
         //   At this point I get the following error:Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value


            self.activity.startAnimating()
        case false:
            self.activity.stopAnimating()
        default:
            self.activity.startAnimating()
        } 
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let dao = Dao()

       /// dao.caricamentoDati()
```

Comment: Did you connect the activity view outlet?

Comment: (yes) the component is connected correctly in my storyboard

Comment: Apparently not otherwise you wouldn't get the error. Put a breakpoint on the `self.activity.startAnimating()` line and you will find that `self.activity` is `nil`.

Comment: @rmaddy he is creating a new object of `FirstViewController` in init of `Dao` and that's creating the problem, see my answer for more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a new object of `FirstViewController` in init of `Dao`. Since `FirstViewController` object is not created via xib/storyboard hence the outlet is not connected. That's why it's giving crash at `self.activity.startAnimating()`

Set the delegate to `self` in `viewDidLoad`

Change your Doa's init method as follow

```
class Dao: NSObject {

  var delegate: ProgressBarDelegate?
    init(delegate: ProgressBarDelegate) {
    super.init()
    //DELEGATO
    //I who should I send the message? to FirstViewController
    self.delegate = delegate
    scriviUnMessaggio(progress: true)
  }
  func scriviUnMessaggio(progress: Bool){
    print("I'm writing a message ...")
    delegate?.UpdateProgressBar(progress:progress)
}
```

Then in viewDidLoad do this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  let dao = Dao(delegate: self)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I get the same error :(

Comment: @Diego Let me know if the edited answer works for you

Comment: at this point of your "self.delegate = delegate" code I get this compile error: "Can not assign value of type 'UIViewController' to type 'ProgressBarDelegate?'"

Comment: Changed the typed of delegate in `Dao` init, see the updated answer

Comment: Now really it works thanks !!!. There is no correct logic on how to use this pattern. Many Internet sites write the examples differently.